# Wordpress wp-admin menu doesn't reroute after updating changes

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

So anytime I change anything in the wp-admin menu i.e search for plugin, install a plugin, activate a plugin, create a new page, create a new post, etc (you get the idea).  It goes to a blank page and doesn't redirect.  For example I hit update on a page and instead of redirecting back to the edit page with the "Your page has been updated" it just goes blank.  The changes save but I have to refresh instead of the automatic redirect.  I am using a custom wordpress theme I created today and am curious what could be causing this.  Thanks in advance.

Update:  Deactivating plugins reroutes, but nothing else seems to.

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen when you use the default theme? It probably has something to do with your database though. Do you have wp_debug enabled? Maybe it'll tell you something about the problem. If nothing helps try deleting the database and install wordpress again.

Comment: This is only happening on my custom theme.  Curious if there is anywhere to look to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: I'd start with functions.php, try empting it completely. Maybe you have some empty lines there that are causing the problem..